# texlive 2021 not finding a file which texlive 2017 can find

Tags: graphics, texlive-2017

In an old version of a file from a TexLive 2017 compile the following line compiles correctly.

```
\node[draw,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt] (quiz) at ($(current page.north)+(0in,-1.25in)$) {\includegraphics[angle=0,width=\dimexpr\aewidth pt- 1cm]{fig/exit_slip/{exit_slip.w01.3.lec.01}.pdf}};
```

But in TexLive 2021, I get the following error

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `fig/exit_slip/{exit_slip.w01.3.lec.01}.pdf' n
ot found: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.81 ...ig/exit_slip/{exit_slip.w01.3.lec.01}.pdf}
                                                  };
```

The file exists and is name correctly.  If I compile under TexLive 2017, there are no errors raised.

What's changed for 2021 (or something inbetween the years) that this no longer works?

Comment: does your actual file have `{}` in its filename?

Comment: for filename handling simpler to ask what is the same, spaces and utf-8 non ascii filenames are allowed by default which required "some refactoring"

Comment: To answer your question:  no curly brackets in the file name.  It seems that when I needed to compile this way back when, I had to add the `{}` because LaTeX kept parsing the extension incorrectly.

Comment: @A.Ellett You probably should have loaded `grffile` at the time instead of using braces.

Comment: @egreg I just found your answer to that effect.

Comment: @A.Ellett parsing is improved and braces shouldn't be needed now (and will be taken as literal characters) for compatibility an intital brace group  disropped but as you have `aaa/bbb/{x.y.z}.pdf` no special handling of the brace group is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current releases multiple `.` (and UTF-8 non ascii filenames and filenames with spaces) are supported by default. Thus `{..}` to hide initial dots are not needed. The common case of a leading brace group `{file.with.dot}.png` is supported for compatibility and the initial brace group is dropped but in your case with a leading directory path, the braces are no longer treated specially and are taken as a literal part of the filename.